# Shrinking background image dependant on screen width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a homepage with a large background image set top and center.  The image is 780px high.

(I am using Bootstrap on Joomla T3 framework)

This looks great on an HD screen and even at slightly lower resoluions, but when you get down to tablet / phone screen size this simply takes up too much space - People would have to scroll down a page or more to get to content.

Here's the CSS:

```css
.homepage {
    background: #fff url("../images/home_back.jpg") no-repeat top center; 
}
```

I would like to do keep the image but perhaps scale it down for lower resolution screens.  Ideally, the background would simply shift up, so that it just never takes up more than 3/4 of the screen...

In short, is there a way to have the background go to a minus-y position relative to the screen width and height?

EDIT:
Browser support required:
All current main desktop browsers, and very importantly, iPad + Android tablets.

Comment: Use `background-size` with a percentage value.

Comment: what browsers are you supporting? the answer might be different depending on what you are supporting. i.e. ios has issues with background-size

Comment: the 'media queries' and 'backgroud-size' will probably do the trick

Comment: Media queries to detect smaller screen size, and background-position to move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's the solution that worked best for my needs.  Thanks guys for the advice:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 980px) {
.homepage {
    background: #fff url("../images/home_back.jpg") no-repeat top center; 
}
}

@media all and (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 480px) {
.homepage {
    background: #fff url("../images/home_back.jpg") no-repeat top center; 
    background-size: auto 550px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.homepage {
    background: #fff url("../images/home_back.jpg") no-repeat top center; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately that just fills the screen with the image.